# Camera for DirectX C++ game

Tags: c++, directx

My camera is not working that well. I tried copying some camera code I had lying around that was written for an OpenGL game, but it seems that in DirectX, I do not get the same results. The problem is that the movement (front and right vectors) is wrong. Sometimes, forward is forward and sometimes it goes right. It depends on the direction I am rotated.

The DX game code:

```
auto position = m_position;
auto positionVector = XMLoadFloat3(&position);

auto lookAt = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
auto lookAtVector = XMLoadFloat3(&lookAt);

auto pitch = m_rotation.x * DEG2RAD_CONSTANT;
auto yaw = m_rotation.y * DEG2RAD_CONSTANT;
auto roll = m_rotation.z * DEG2RAD_CONSTANT;
auto rotationMatrix = XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw(pitch, yaw, roll);

XMFLOAT3 front;
front.z = -(cosf(yaw) * cosf(pitch));
front.y = -sinf(pitch);
front.x = sinf(yaw) * cosf(pitch);
m_front = front;

lookAtVector = XMVector3TransformCoord(lookAtVector, rotationMatrix);
lookAtVector = XMVectorAdd(positionVector, lookAtVector);
m_viewMatrix = XMMatrixLookAtLH(positionVector, lookAtVector, m_up);
```

Comment: This may or may not be to do with this, but the coordinate systems in OpenGL and DirectX are different: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17519/why-does-directx-use-a-left-handed-coordinate-system

Comment: That is not entirely true since you can select which type of handedness you want in both.

Comment: This is true. Are you using the same handedness?

Comment: No, because using the same as in OpenGL results in a massive amount of errors. The two worlds are so vastly different. DX really feels old :(